# React-redux - Console Error on using npm d3 and the PieChart

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, pie-chart

Below is the error which i am getting in my react-redux application.

```
AppPieChart.tsx:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

**data.map** is highlighted in console as an error

```
 <div className="legend">
   <svg width="230" height="230">
          {
            data.map(
              (value,i)=>{
                  return(
                      <g key={i} className="legend" transform={translate(50, 49-i*5)} >
                        <rect width="15" height="15" y={i*30} fill={value.stroke} rx="15"/>
                        <text x={19} y={11+i*30}>{value.label}</text>
                      </g>
                    )
              })
          }      
        </svg>
     </div>
```

In Above component i am exporting **Piechart** and importing it in another component but currently i am getting console error.

I guess this error is very common and everyone might be aware of it hence let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: You are inputing data to map function which is not defined. Please post the specific line which is causing issue

Comment: Sure @G_S I have included the statements causing error

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a valid 'data' object here?

Comment: Yes @G_S - I am getting it as prop data plus initially i am initializing it like -' let data = this.props.data'

Comment: Can you please do a console of data in your render method after you have initialized it?

Comment: No @G_S i am getting it as undefined.. i checked it in console just now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165407/discussion-between-g-s-and-martin-m).

Answer (score 0):

Note that Suppressing errors are bad with a null check can be bad in future. 
Check if you have valid data (if its defined or not) and then make a call to data.map

```
<div className="legend">
   <svg width="230" height="230">
          {
           data && data.map(
              (value,i)=>{
                  return(
                      <g key={i} className="legend" transform={translate(50, 49-i*5)} >
                        <rect width="15" height="15" y={i*30} fill={value.stroke} rx="15"/>
                        <text x={19} y={11+i*30}>{value.label}</text>
                      </g>
                    )
              })
          }      
        </svg>
     </div>
```

Comment: yes you are right @G_S, i am getting data undefined.